# Submitting Files With {exp:channel:form}

Tags: channel-entries, safecracker, forms

EE 5.2.2

I'm using the `{exp:channel:form}` tag to create an order reporting feature that will save a generated report as an EE channel entry.

The feature currently has a form that accepts parameters, submits those to an Amazon API, and returns the result (XML report for orders) as a JSON object. If the object is received successfully then the old form is hidden and a new form is shown. This form is a `{exp:channel:form}` tag.

I've been able to get this tag to submit an entry to the channel with a title that is generated based on the previously submitted parameters, and that works fine. I also have two links that show along with the new form as a part of the result of this query: a link to view the new file and a link to download it (these are both done using the JavaScript Blob object, and both of them are working:

```
var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
a.attr('href', URL.createObjectURL(file));
a.attr('download', name + '.txt');
v.attr('href', URL.createObjectURL(file));
t.attr('value', name);
```

The problem I'm having *now* is this: how to save this new file in a input (preferably hidden) that can be submitted to the channel along with the title?

I have these two docs open: [this one](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/channel-form/fields.html#file-field) and [this one](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channels/channel-form/examples.html#entry-forms-using-manually-constructed-file-field). I'm not quite sure how to interpret this, though. They both have this as an example:

```
<input type="file" name="my_field_name" />
<input type="hidden" name="my_field_name_directory" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="my_field_name_hidden_file" value="{my_field_name}{file_name}{/my_field_name}" />
```

What I have in my form is this:

```
{exp:channel:form channel="order_reports" return="/{my_index}"}
    <a href="" id="download_link">Download File</a>
    <a href="" id="view_link" target="_blank">View File</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="title">
    <input type="file" name="my_field_name" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my_field_name_directory" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="my_field_name_hidden_file" value="{file}{title}{/file}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
{/exp:channel:form}
```

Now, I'm obviously not doing this right, but I'm not entirely sure how to interpret the documentation. And I'd ideally like to put this new file into a hidden input so the user doesn't have to go through another step to save the file to the channel, so if there's some way that I could put my Blob object into an input as a .txt file, the same way I'm doing it with my two links, that would be perfect.

Thanks for any help and/or clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar trouble with a file field in Channel Forms, can you confirm the value for the name=“my_field_name_directory” input is the file directory number?